# How to add an ImageView to a TableRow in code

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I'm tryin to add an ImageView into a TableRow in Java, but it always shows in blank. The image seems to be there, but it is completely white.

This is my code:

```
TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
newRow.setId(1);
LayoutParams lptr = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newRow.setLayoutParams(lptr);
newRow.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

ImageView pImg = new ImageView(this);
pImg.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error));
newRow.addView(pImg);
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: Have you added the new row to the `TableLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten two thing:

1) you have forgotten `setContentView(view);`

2) you have forgotten to add your `TableRow` to `TableLayout`